# How to concatenate two states in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have state

```
export interface ChatMessagesState {
  messages: Message[] | null;
  chatId: string;
}
```

in the websocket, data may come that will be something like this

```
newMessages: Message[] = [
{
    text: 'Hello',
    chatId: '100'
},
{
    text: 'Hello 2',
    chatId: '101'
}
]
```

and so, I want to update add a separate message to the state (concatenate them) if the chatIds match, and if not, then do not add. Where should this be done, in the reducer? Or in the facade?

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate? If you want to add messages to the store you should use a reducer. In the reducer compare the chatId and then decide to add or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That logic should exist in the reducer because it holds the state.
This means that you can easily read the state within the reducer to decide if it should append the message or not.
In my apps, all of the logic to check what/if it needs to update state lives in reducers.

Comment: That`s not right.. reducers do not hold data. Reducers are supposed to be lean functions used to  update the store/data.

Comment: Yea, it's worded badly from my end, but they receive their state as an argument.